Python function to save viewport render through an operator that manages already existing files
Good morning to everyone. Total python newbie here, tinkering with Geometry nodes to create a program configurator for my company.
As I am no programmer at all, practically, in order to speed up my work I'm having some of the functions I use being created by ChatGPT and then verify their correct functioning / correcting them to suit my needs.
I'm struggling with one, thought, which I am unable to make it work.
My need is to have an operator that takes a folder path and a filename, joins them as a full path and sets it as the destination for the render result. Everything almost works up to this point (except that the rendering function seems to happen twice, once without any prompt and the second with the cancel/overwrite prompt window appearing), however... if the file already exists (and based on what I just wrote, it always "already exists" because the rendering process happens twice), I'm not able to prevent the operator to overwrite it even by choosing "Cancel" (i.e. the "render.cancel_overwrite" operator), let alone the "Overwrite" (i.e. the "render.confirm_overwrite" function) and the popup prompt never disappears.
Is anyone able to point me to a solution?
This is the operator code together with the overwrite and cancel functions
class RENDER_OT_SaveRender(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Save Render to File without opening Render Window"""
    bl_idname = "render.save_render"
    bl_label = "Save Render"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    confirm_overwrite: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)
    file_path: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="")

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        scene = context.scene

        # Get the output folder and filename
        output_path = os.path.normpath(bpy.path.abspath(scene.render_output_path))
        filename = scene.render_output_filename
        self.file_path = os.path.join(output_path, filename)
 
        # Check if the file already exists
        if os.path.exists(self.file_path) and not self.confirm_overwrite:
            # Launch a custom popup for overwrite confirmation
            return context.window_manager.invoke_popup(self, width=300)

        # Proceed with execution if no file exists
        return self.execute(context)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text=f"File already exists:\n{self.file_path}")
        layout.label(text="Do you want to overwrite it?")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("render.confirm_overwrite", text="Overwrite", icon='CHECKMARK')
        row.operator("render.cancel_overwrite", text="Cancel", icon='CANCEL')

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene

        # Ensure the output folder exists
        output_path = os.path.normpath(bpy.path.abspath(scene.render_output_path))
        if not os.path.isdir(output_path):
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "Output folder does not exist")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        # Full file path for saving
        full_path = self.file_path
        # Set the render output path temporarily
        scene.render.filepath = full_path
        # Render and save the image
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class RENDER_OT_ConfirmOverwrite(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Overwrite confirmation"""
    bl_idname = "render.confirm_overwrite"
    bl_label = "Confirm Overwrite"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    def execute(self, context):
        # Set flag for overwrite and re-trigger save render
        bpy.ops.render.save_render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', confirm_overwrite=True)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class RENDER_OT_CancelOverwrite(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Cancel overwrite"""
    bl_idname = "render.cancel_overwrite"
    bl_label = "Cancel Overwrite"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Render cancelled by user")
        return {'CANCELLED'}

And this is how the operator is placed in the N panel subpanel which I created:
row.label(text="Export Image File", icon = 'FILE_TICK')
row = box.row()
box.prop(scene, "render_output_path")
box.prop(scene, "render_output_filename")
row = box.row()
row.operator("render.save_render", text="Save to file")


Hello, in my experience working with chatGPT you should start small and add function little by little, here it has spewn out something that will not work and the time needed to debug it will surpass the time it would take to make it from scratch. Just my 2 cents why someone downvoted you and you may never get an answer here. Cheers
